# SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2012 Install

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, installation

I'm trying to upgrade one of my SQL servers from 2008R2 to 2012 and I'm getting an error popup within a couple of seconds from starting the setup

The Error is

> ### TITLE: SQL Server Setup failure.
>
> `SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:
>   There was a failure to calculate the applicability of setting UIMODE.
>   Error code 0x85640002.For help, click:http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&EvtType=0xC6B69F4C%25400xDC80C325`

The Microsoft help link is [here](http://www.microsoft.com/products/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&EvtType=0xC6B69F4C%25400xDC80C325)

I've spent a good amount of time searching for this error on google and stackoverflow to no avail. I've only found errors that are kind of like it that have to do with this

> There was a failure to calculate the applicability of setting ALLINSTANCES

What I've tried.

- I ran a dotnet repair tool from Microsoft
- Ran as Admin/From a different account
- Installing from a cmd prompt using `uimode=Normal action=Install`
  and `uimode=autoadvance action=install`.
- Unzipping ISO to C: drive and ran install from there.
- Re-downloaded the ISO to see if it was a corrupt download.
- Downloaded SQL Server 2012 SP2 installer.

All of these have failed to get past this error. The below link is from the install log located at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log`

Install Log http://pastebin.com/Z71VSgg9

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Is it necessary to upgrade ? I mean, did you tried to uninstall 2008 R2 and install 2012 ?

Comment: I can't remove 2008R2 as this is a production server. Yes I will need to upgrade to 2012 before the summer is over with.

Comment: We generally had custom culture installed on the server which is used for Epic Application Reporting where in the regional settings was set. Revert the regional settings of the OS to English (United States).

Then Unpack the ISO using WinRAR and run .exe with admin privileges.

Comment: I've tried all those and still I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Can you list out what other softwares are running on the server?

Comment: Relativity and the server is Server 2008R2 other than those two things there shouldn't be any major applications on there. Are you looking for something in particular?